# make div appear on only 1 of many image rollovers

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden div with class `hidden_thing` that is positioned in the center of an image and then hidden using CSS visibility. I can switch it to visible with the following jQuery, but I have many images on the page with the same class `cat_image_table`. So how do I select on the currently rolled over image?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.cat_image_table').on("mouseenter", function(){
        $('.hidden_thing').fadeIn(300)
    });

    $('.cat_image_table').on("mouseleave", function(){
        $('.hidden_thing').fadeOut('slow')
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.cat_image_table {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    width:255px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-spacing:0;
    border:none;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.hidden_thing {
   position: absolute;
   top: 130px;
   left: 50px;
   width:150px;
   height:30px;
   background: #EE1B2C;
   padding-top:5px;
   color:white;
   font-family:allerBold;
   font-size:20px;
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

PHP:

```
<div class="cat_image_table">

    <a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_INFO, ($cPath ? 'cPath=' . $cPath . '&' : '') . 'products_id=' . $listing['products_id']) . '">' . tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES_CAT . $listing['products_image'], $listing['products_name'], 255, 340, 'class="cat_image_round"') . '</a>

</div>

<div class="hidden_thing">Click to View</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be some sort of structural relationship between each `cat_image_table` and its associated `hidden_thing` for this to be possible.

Say `hidden_thing` were a child of the `cat_image_table` then you could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.cat_image_table')
        .on("mouseenter", function(){
            $(this).find('.hidden_thing').fadeIn(300);
        })
        .on("mouseleave", function(){
            $(this).find('.hidden_thing').fadeOut('slow');
        });
});
```

(It would help to post an example of your markup)

Comment: Ok so apparently I dont have a structural relationship because this is not working for me. Is it because the hidden div is outside of the other div? I posted the php above.

Comment: Ok So moving the hidden div within the image div works perfectly. So I guess that is what you meant? If you have the time can you explain that to me quickly?

Comment: Yes, I just made an assumption you would have your markup structured on some way that a relationship between the 2 elements could be inferred - otherwise how would it work? If you can structure it as I've suggested then great.

Answer (score 1):

try $(this).

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.cat_image_table').on("mouseenter", function(){
        $(this).find('.hidden_thing').show();
    });
});
```

Also, use the method `.show()` and `.hide()` to show and hide elements. It will normalize the visibility across browsers, resulting in a more effective approach to your task.

Comment: but using this implies that its the cat_image_table class that will be shown, Which already is shown. It is the hidden_thing class that needs to be shown

Comment: Right, my bad! Did not realize. I updated to suit your structure.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, But I guess I left out the fact as I mentioned to Duncan that they don't have a structural relationship? I'm not sure what that means yet but I updated my post with some php